# Applying FTOC II to Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Question: http://puu.sh/zmunb/3f1702f677.png

To be quite honest, I have no idea how I would approach this question so I do not have anything for you guys to tell me to work off of. I was wondering if I could get a hint as to how I can start this? Thanks!

edit: I'm not sure if my title is accurate, I'm just assuming we would use FTOC II based of the upper limit.

Comment: Well, you take a derivative and show it's zero. Fundamental Theorem is how you take a derivative here.

Comment: (1) Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.
(2) Links from external sites are succumb to 404 Error.

Comment: The integral is considered as a function of x,  let's call it I(x). Then  the assertion is that the integral actually does not depend on x, but that then means that the function I(x) is a constant function. The derivative of a constant function is zero, and the FTOC says something about derivatives of integrals.

Comment: This is a duplicate. If all you want is a hint, don't look. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.